# How to show/hide div with toggle in different page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I have toggle on the options page which should show / hide div on another page. With some help here on stack I was able to structure this code, but I can't get it to work.

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/mLonrbkf/1/

1. I can't show / hide the divs
2. I don't understand how to save in localstorage

I would like to understand what values the functions of the Js code must assume. Can anyone help me?

```js
function setSetting(name,value){
  window.localStorage.setItem(name,true);
}
function getSetting(name){
  return window.localStorage.getItem(name);
}

const div = document.querySelector("label-ck1");

if(getSetting("show")){
  div.style.display = "block";
}
else{
  div.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck1">
  <span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>

<label class="switch">
   <input type="checkbox" id="ck2">
   <span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>

<div class="hideme" id="label-ck1">Please hide me...</div>
<div class="hideme" id="label-ck2">Please hide me...</div>
```

Comment: Where do you call `setSetting`?

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to all of this, the code you see I structured with the help of stack users. I'm not very good at these things, so I can't answer your question. I'm trying to figure out how to complete the code and what's wrong.

Comment: Originally, the working code looked like this: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/rk689wqb/3/

But the suggestion I was given is to work with Js code posted in this question. But I don't know how ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied what you wrote in your original code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/mLonrbkf/1/) using the same css I found there. Then I just rewrote the javascript part.

What it does is attaching a change event handler to any checkbox found on the page so that when their state it's changed, the corresponding label gets shown or hidden. The corresponding label is found using the checkbox id with the prefix `label-`.

In that event, the state of the checkbox changed gets pushed in the localStorage. At the very beginning, the page first checks if there's any state saved for each of the checkbox found and in case there is, its state gets updated correspondingly.

In Firefox `localStorage` methods `(getItem/setItem)` return `SecurityError: The operation is insecure`. I could run that code on a dedicated html page to verify it's working correctly (on Chrome for sure). So to avoid any problem at first, I added a securityFlag on top of the js code. When that flag is set to true, the localStorage won't be engaged at all so that you could see the preview here with no errors.

```js
//if set to true, any operation involving localStorage will be excluded
let securityFlag = true;

/**
 * Initialize the Checkboxes state according to what's stored on localStorage
 */
function initCheckboxStateBasedOnLocalStorage(){
    //for each of the checkboxes on the page
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach( (checkbox, i) => {
    
        //if securityFlag is true, skip the operation
        if(securityFlag) return;
    
        //retrieves the value stored in localStorage paired to the id passed
        let valueStored = window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id);
        //if valueStored is set
        if(valueStored == 'true' || valueStored == 'false')
            //sets the checkbox value with what was retrieved from localStorage
            checkbox.checked = valueStored == 'true' ? true : false;
    });
}

/**
 * Will hide/show the label corresponding to checkbox and will save its value on localStorage
 * It will be registered as the handler of the change event of every checkbox in the page
 */
function onCheckBoxStateChange(){

    let checkbox = event.target;

    //guesses the id of the label dedicated to the checkbox triggering the event
    let msgContainer = document.getElementById(`label-${checkbox.id}`);
    //if this checkbox is checked,
    if (checkbox.checked){
        //show the corresponding label
        msgContainer.style.display = "block";
        //if securityFlag is true, skip the operation
        if(securityFlag) return;
        //sets the state in localStorage for this.id
        window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id ,true);
    }
    //otherwise
    else{
        //hide the corresponding label
        msgContainer.style.display = "none";
        //if securityFlag is true, skip the operation
        if(securityFlag) return;
        //sets the state in localStorage for this.id
        window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id ,false);
    }
}

//When the document has been loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  //for each of the checkboxes on the page
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach( (checkbox, i) => {
    //attach an handler to the event change
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", onCheckBoxStateChange );
  });
});

//reflect the value of checkboxed according to what's stored on localStorage
initCheckboxStateBasedOnLocalStorage();
```

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
  }
  
  .switch input { 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
  }
  
  /* Rounded sliders */
  .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
  .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

/*END OF TOGGLE SWITCH*/

.hideme {
  padding:20px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>checkbox1</p>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="ck1">
  <span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>

<br><br>

<p>checkbox2</p>
<label class="switch">    
   <input type="checkbox" id="ck2">
   <span class="slider round hide-off"></span>
</label>
<br><br>

<div class="hideme" id="label-ck1">Label bound to checkbox1</div>
<div class="hideme" id="label-ck2">Label bound to checkbox2</div>
```

In case you need a fully workable solution out of the box, I uploaded a set of files on pastebin as being:

| File | Download link |
| --- | --- |
| demo.html | https://pastebin.com/mHWQ7564 |
| style.css | https://pastebin.com/3jzTubFR |
| logic.js | https://pastebin.com/uFDrGrZx |

Save them on your local computer inside the same folder and please make sure the filenames are exactly how I listed on that table. Then load the file demo.html from your web browser.

It's a slightly modified version of what I shared here. Its behavior is fully consistent with any initial condition. I also added, for the sake of further education, a strategy to add new checkbox-label pairs to the page programmatically.

There are buttons on top of the page to:

- Add a new checkbox
- Reset the local storage
- Reload the page

There's a lot to digest there if you are not familiar with developing web pages yet. Good luck!

Comment: First, thanks for the reply. You have been very kind, I appreciate that.

I am doing several tests both on my website and on JsFiddle but the toggles don't seem to memorize the status of the divs. Also I don't understand why here on stack run codesnippet it works, while the same code doesn't on Jsfiddle or my site.

However, even if the divs start hidden here on the stack, I don't know if they are actually stored in local storage. However when I restart the page they reset.

Comment: the problem with localStorage is that it's bound to the origin where the page comes from. When dealing with cookies and anything like that bound to the origin, things are not easy to test beyond those constraints. If you put that code inside a local html file and you open with chrome it will surely work. Of course after you changed the state of both checkboxes, only in that moment both the checkbox status will be saved in localStorage. When you'll open the local html page, the origin won't be bound to stackoverflow.com or any other remote origin.

Comment: Anyway I don't want you to just copy and paste my code.. I hope you understand what it does and that's why I commented every single line. So that you could fix it according to your preference as soon as you finally got where the magic lies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the way you commented to make me understand how to modify everything at will. I must say that my level of knowledge on Js is very low.

I'm trying to make some changes to make it work, but I can't. I don't understand which are the values that I can change and which are not. So I am really sorry for my lack knowledge, but I am unable to go further.

Comment: The first test was to enter the code as it was written by you, but it didn't work. Nothing is simply stored.

Then, following your comments I did a bit of google research to understand what valueStored, let, addEventListener etc. do.

Later I tried to change the ids and a few other things like false and true values.

In conclusion I didn't understand anything, lol.

Comment: local storage will not save the state of the div, but it will save the state of the buttons position, so you have to store both data in local storage

Comment: yes exactly, as I perfectly explained in my answer. Wait a moment and I'll add some further details

Comment: I apologize for taking so long. By the way eventually I found the time to update my answer and add a new version better dealing with any initial state and providing better tools to the users to further experiment. I hope you'll be able to run the demo I shared and I wish you the best learning what you still miss to understand what happens there in details.